# How does FallbackValue work with a MultiBinding?

Tags: wpf, multibinding, fallbackvalue

I ask because it doesn't seem to work.

Assume we're binding to the following object:

```
public class HurrDurr
{
  public string Hurr {get{return null;}}
  public string Durr {get{return null;}}
}
```

Well, it would appear that if we used a **MultiBinding** against this the fallback value would be shown, right?

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>                                
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} to the {1}"
                        FallbackValue="Not set!  It works as expected!)">
            <Binding Path="Hurr"/>
            <Binding Path="Durr"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

However the result is, in fact, **" to the "**.
Even forcing the bindings to return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` doesn't work:

```
<TextBlock xmnlns:base="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=WindowsBase">
    <TextBlock.Text>                                
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} to the {1}"
            FallbackValue="Not set!  It works as expected!)">
            <Binding Path="Hurr"
                FallbackValue="{x:Static base:DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" />
            <Binding Path="Durr"
                FallbackValue="{x:Static base:DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Tried the same with **TargetNullValue**, which was also a bust all the way around.

So it appears that **MultiBinding** will never ever use **FallbackValue**.  Is this true, or am I missing something?

---

A little more messing around and I found that a converter can return the UnsetValue I need:

```
class MultiValueFailConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || 
            values.Length != 2 ||
            values.Any(x=>x == null))
            return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        return values;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, 
        Type[] targetTypes, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Too complex hurt brain.");
    }
}
```

However, this seems like a dirty filthy hack.  I'd think a scenario like this would be accounted for in the framework.  I can't find anything in Reflector, however.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bit of an old question, but it could use some explanation.

From the [FallbackValue documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx):

> A binding returns a value successfully if:
>
> 1. The path to the binding source resolves successfully.
> 2. The value converter, if any, is able to convert the resulting value.
> 3. The resulting value is valid for the binding target (target) property.
>
> If 1 and 2 return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, the target property
>   is set to the value of the FallbackValue, if one is available. If
>   there is no FallbackValue, the default value of the target property is
>   used.

In the example provided, the binding successfully resolves to the `Hurr` and `Durr` properties. Null is valid value for a string which means the binding is valid.

In other words, the FallbackValue is used when the binding is unable to return a value and in the example provided, the binding does provide a valid value.

Take for example each of the following snippets that are based off the original example:

*Example 1*
The Hurr and Durr properties are bound correctly; null is a valid value and the FallbackValue will never be seen.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding FallbackValue="Binding is valid. I will never be seen." StringFormat="{}{0} to the {1}">
            <Binding Path="Hurr" />
            <Binding Path="Durr" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

*Example 2*
The Hurr and Durr properties are not bound correctly; the FallbackValue will be seen.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding FallbackValue="Binding paths are invalid. Look at me." StringFormat="{}{0} to the {1}">
            <Binding Path="xHurr" />
            <Binding Path="xDurr" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

*Example 3*
If one binding path is invalid, then the FallbackValue will be seen.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding FallbackValue="One binding path is invalid. Look at me." StringFormat="{}{0} to the {1}">
            <Binding Path="xHurr" />
            <Binding Path="Durr" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

*Example 4*
As with previous examples, the binding is correct, so the FallbackValue will not be used. Further, the FallbackValue for each of the child `Binding` properties of the `MultiBinding` parent should refer to a FallbackValue to be used for the target property of the MultiBinding, not for the child Bindings.

```
<TextBlock xmlns:base="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=WindowsBase">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding FallbackValue="Binding is valid. I will never be seen." StringFormat="{}{0} to the {1}">
            <Binding FallbackValue="{x:Static base:DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" Path="Hurr" />
            <Binding FallbackValue="{x:Static base:DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" Path="Durr" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

*Example 5*
The binding is still valid even though a path is not provided in `Binding` properties since the binding will use whatever object it is bound to.

```
<TextBlock xmlns:base="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=WindowsBase">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding FallbackValue="Binding is still valid. I will never be seen." StringFormat="{}{0} to the {1}">
            <Binding FallbackValue="{x:Static base:DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" />
            <Binding FallbackValue="{x:Static base:DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

*Example 6*
Finally, if a converter is added to any of the Binding properties to force an UnsetValue, then the MultiBinding FallbackValue will be seen:

**Converter**

```
internal class ForceUnsetValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IValueConverter

    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding FallbackValue="Binding is valid, but look at me. I'm an UnsetValue." StringFormat="{}{0} to the {1}">
            <Binding Converter="{StaticResource ForceUnset}" Path="Hurr" />
            <Binding Path="Durr" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```